# Necesito que mi funcion invertir numero funcione con las demas funciones

Tags: c++

MI código está implementado con funciones, en las cuales se ingresa un número en base decimal y me transforma a dos bases: binaria y hexadecimal.

Mi problema es cuando lo presenta de forma no invertida y tengo la función `invertir_numero` pero no se como implementarla con las demás funciones. Estoy aprendiendo C++ y quisiera saber en qué me equivoco. Por favor, les agradecería su respuesta.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int conversion_binario(int numero);
int invertir_numero(int num);
int conversion_hexadecimal(int num);
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"El numero ingresado equivale a binario en : "<<invertir_numero(conversion_binario(n))<<endl;
    cout<<"El numero ingresado equivale a hexadecimal en : "<<conversion_hexadecimal(n);
    return 0;
}
int conversion_binario(int numero){
    int residuo,cociente,aux;
    do{
        residuo=numero%2;
        cociente=numero/2;
        aux=cociente;
        numero=0;
        numero=aux;
        cout<<residuo;
    }while(numero>=2);
    return numero;
}
int invertir_numero(int num){
    int numero=conversion_binario(numero);
    while(numero>=10){
    cout<<(numero%10);
    numero/=10;
    }
    return numero;
}
int conversion_hexadecimal(int num){
    int residuo,cociente,aux;
    do{
        residuo=num%16;
        cociente=num/16;
        aux=cociente;
        num=0;
        num=aux;

        if(residuo==10){
            cout << "A";
        }else if(residuo==11){
            cout << "B";
        }else  if(residuo==12){
            cout << "C";
        }else if(residuo==13){
            cout << "D";
        }else if(residuo==14){
            cout << "E";
        }else if(residuo==15){
            cout << "F";
        }
        cout << residuo;
    }while(num >= 16);
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nota incial:** No tienes que incrementar la tabulación de `else if`. No solo no es necesario sino que es contraproducente... deberían estar todos al mismo nivel y la razón de ello es que el `else if` no está dentro de las llaves del `if`:

```
if(residuo==10){
    cout<<"A";
}else if(residuo==11){
    cout<<"B";
}else  if(residuo==12){
    cout<<"C";
}else if(residuo==13){
    cout<<"D";
}else if(residuo==14){
    cout<<"E";
}else if(residuo==15){
    cout<<"F";
}
cout<<residuo;
```

Así es más facil ver que tu conversión a hexadecimal **no funciona**, ya que **siempre** vas a hacer `cout << residuo`, incluso cuando `residuo >= 10`.

```
if(residuo==10){
    cout<<"A";
}else if(residuo==11){
    cout<<"B";
}else  if(residuo==12){
    cout<<"C";
}else if(residuo==13){
    cout<<"D";
}else if(residuo==14){
    cout<<"E";
}else if(residuo==15){
    cout<<"F";
} else {
    cout<<residuo;
}
```

Tabular bien es muy importante. Ayuda a leer mejor el código y permite detectar pufos más facilmente

> tengo la función invertir_numero pero no se como implementarla con las demás funciones

Es que no tienes que invertir el número. Has de invertir el resultado.

El problema que tienes es que cuando realizas conversiones, los primeros dígitos que obtienes son los menos representativos... mientras que a la hora de representar dichos números solemos dejar dichos dígitos al final.

Dicho con un ejemplo: El número 85 tiene dos dígitos. El `8` es el más representativo (da una mayor certeza acerca del número final), mientras que el `5`  es el menos representativo. Sin embargo si intentamos extraer sus dígitos:

```
int numero = 85;
do
{
  std::cout << numero % 10;
  numero /= 10;
} while( numero != 0 );
```

Vemos que el primer dígito extraído es el menos representativo.

Así pues la solución pasa por invertir la secuencia de salida. ¿Cómo se hace eso?

Pues te toca almacenar el resultado para, posteriormente, darle la vuelta:

```
int conversion_hexadecimal(int num){
    std::string resultado;
    int residuo,cociente,aux;
    do{
        residuo=num%16;
        cociente=num/16;
        aux=cociente;
        num=0;
        num=aux;
        if(residuo==10){
            resultado += 'A';
        }else if(residuo==11){
            resultado += 'B';
        } // ...
    }while(num>=16);

    // Metodo 1
    std::reverse(resultado.begin(), resultado.end())
    std::cout << resultado;

    // Metodo 2
    std::cout << std::string(resultado.rbegin(), resultado.rend());

    // Metodo 3
    for( int i=resultado.size()-1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
      std::cout << resultado[i];
    }


    return num;
}
```

Aunque a mi personalmente me parece demasiado código para lo que hace realmente la función:

- No entiendo por qué debe devolver `num`
- Demasiadas comprobaciones
- Demasiadas variables

Una aproximación:

```
std::string conversion_hexadecimal(int num)
{
    constexpr char const* base16 = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    std::string resultado;

    do
    {
        int residuo = num % 16;
        num /= 16;

        resultado += base16[residuo];
    } while( num != 0 );

    std::reverse(resultado.begin(), resultado.end());
    return resultado;
}

std::cout << conversion_hexadecimal(15348);
```

Comment: pues muchas gracias amigo tu solucion es muy eficaz .. aunque no entiendo un poco de lo que implementas soy un poco nuevo en c++ pero me gusta tu solucion ,muchisimas gracias de antemano por tu ayuda

Comment: @user97805 qué no entiendes?

Answer (score 0):

Observa esta posibilidad usando string. En tu caso me parece perfecta.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string conversion_binario(int numero);
string conversion_hexadecimal(int numero);
string invertir_numero(string num);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"El numero ingresado equivale a binario en : "<<invertir_numero(conversion_binario(n))<<endl;
    cout<<"El numero ingresado equivale a hexadecimal en : "<<invertir_numero(conversion_hexadecimal(n))<<endl;
    return 0;
}

string conversion_binario(int numero)
{
    string binario = "";
    int residuo;
    do
    {
        residuo = numero%2;
        numero /= 2;
        binario += residuo?"1":"0";
    }
    while(numero>=2);

    binario += numero?"1":"0";
    return binario;
}

string conversion_hexadecimal(int numero)
{
    string hexadecimal = "";
    int residuo;
    do
    {
        residuo=numero%16;
        numero /= 16;
        switch(residuo)
        {
            case 0:
                hexadecimal += "0";
                break;
            case 1:
                hexadecimal += "1";
                break;
            case 2:
                hexadecimal += "2";
                break;
            case 3:
                hexadecimal += "3";
                break;
            case 4:
                hexadecimal += "4";
                break;
            case 5:
                hexadecimal += "5";
            case 6:
                hexadecimal += "6";
                break;
            case 7:
                hexadecimal += "7";
                break;
            case 8:
                hexadecimal += "8";
                break;
            case 9:
                hexadecimal += "9";
                break;
            case 10:
                hexadecimal += "A";
                break;
            case 11:
                hexadecimal += "B";
                break;
            case 12:
                hexadecimal += "C";
                break;
            case 13:
                hexadecimal += "D";
                break;
            case 14:
                hexadecimal += "E";
                break;
            default:
                hexadecimal += "F";
                break;
        }
    }
    while(numero >= 16);
    switch(numero)
    {
        case 0:
            hexadecimal += "0";
            break;
        case 1:
            hexadecimal += "1";
            break;
        case 2:
            hexadecimal += "2";
            break;
        case 3:
            hexadecimal += "3";
            break;
        case 4:
            hexadecimal += "4";
            break;
        case 5:
            hexadecimal += "5";
        case 6:
            hexadecimal += "6";
            break;
        case 7:
            hexadecimal += "7";
            break;
        case 8:
            hexadecimal += "8";
            break;
        case 9:
            hexadecimal += "9";
            break;
        case 10:
            hexadecimal += "A";
            break;
        case 11:
            hexadecimal += "B";
            break;
        case 12:
            hexadecimal += "C";
            break;
        case 13:
            hexadecimal += "D";
            break;
        case 14:
            hexadecimal += "E";
            break;
        default:
            hexadecimal += "F";
            break;
    }
    return hexadecimal;
}
string invertir_numero(string num)
{
    string aux = "";
    for(int i = num.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        aux += num[i];
    }
    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Si cambias la condición del primer `while` a `numero>=0` te ahorras el segundo `switch`... por otro lado, el `switch` me parece un poco exagerado para hacer la conversión